# How to access nested object from JSON with Json.NET in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

How can I select the json value *"estimatedLocationDate"* within a nested object using class decoration? The property "estimatedLocationDate" always returns `null` instead of the value `2015-10-01T14:00:00.000`. The other decorated values return the proper values.

Here is my `C#` class

```
public string id { get; set; }

public string name { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("publishedDate")]
public string publishdate { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("estimatedLocationDate")]
public string estimatedLocationDate{ get; set; }

[JsonProperty("createdTime")]
public string createtime { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("lastUpdatedTime")]
public string lastupdate { get; set; }
```

And This is the `JSON`

```
"planet": [
    {
        "id": "123456",
        "planetid": "en-us/Jupiter-mars/---main",
        "name": "The planet Mercury",
        "description": "This is placeholder for the description",
        "publishedDate": "2013-10-14T23:30:00.000",
        "createtime": "2012-03-01T14:00:00.000",
        "product": {
            "moreid": "1427-48-bd-9-113",
            "color": "200",
            "imageUrl": "http://image.bing.com/Mercury.jpg",
            "neighbor": [
                {
                    "ring": "Two",
                    "moons": 2
                }
            ],
            "estimatedLocationDate": "2014-10-01T14:00:00.000"
        },
```

Comment: the json posted is invalid

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh code shown may be an excerpt.

Comment: @nvartak Most probably, it is. The OP writes "The other decorated values return the proper values."

Comment: check your code, what you need is "estimatedLocationDate", but the json property is estimatedLaunchDate. that is why your are getting null

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh The json posted is only a snipper.

Comment: @AymanBarhoum Thanks "estimatedLaunchDate" in the class is a typo in my post, the actual code has the correct property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes should look something like this (this is incomplete though):

```
class Planet
    {
        [JsonProperty("planet")]
        PlanetInfo[] planet { get; set; }
    }
    class Product
    {
        [JsonProperty("estimatedLocationDate")]
        string estimatedLocationDate {get;set;}
    }
    class PlanetInfo
    {

        public string id { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("publishedDate")]
        public string publishdate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("estimatedLaunchDate")]
        public string estimatedLaunchDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("createdTime")]
        public string createtime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lastUpdatedTime")]
        public string lastupdate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("product")]
        public Product product { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

The `JSON` you posted is not valid. You can validate your `JSON` at  [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Let's assume below is your `JSON` data.

```
{ "planet": [
        {
            "id": "123456",
            "planetid": "en-us/Jupiter-mars/---main",
            "name": "The planet Mercury",
            "description": "This is placeholder for the description",
            "publishedDate": "2013-10-14T23:30:00.000",
            "createtime": "2012-03-01T14:00:00.000",
            "product": {
                "moreid": "1427-48-bd-9-113",
                "color": "200",
                "imageUrl": "http://image.bing.com/Mercury.jpg",
                "neighbor": [
                    {
                        "ring": "Two",
                        "moons": 2
                    }
                ],
                "estimatedLocationDate": "2014-10-01T14:00:00.000"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The easy way to read the whole `JSON` is to `deserialize` it to proper class hierarchy. If you do not have that already, you can create following these steps in Visual Studio

> - Copy your JSON data
> - Create a new empty class in VS
> - VS > Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes

This are the generated classes

```
public class PlanetRoot
{
    public Planet[] planet { get; set; }
}

public class Planet
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string planetid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Product product { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("publishedDate")]
    public string publishdate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("createdTime")]
    public string createtime { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string moreid { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    public Neighbor[] neighbor { get; set; }
    public DateTime estimatedLocationDate { get; set; }
}

public class Neighbor
{
    public string ring { get; set; }
    public int moons { get; set; }
}
```

Now, it's easy to read the whole object and access your `estimatedLocationDate` like this

```
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\YourDirectory\YourFile.json");

PlanetRoot planet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlanetRoot>(jsonString);
DateTime estimatedLocationDate = planet.planet.First().product.estimatedLocationDate;
```

OR, if you do not want to read the whole object, you can directly read that property using `Json.NET` [**Linq-to-JSON**](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm) like this

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var estLocDate = jObject["planet"][0]["product"]["estimatedLocationDate"].ToObject<DateTime>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `product` represents another object, you will need to create a class for it:

```
public class Planet  
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("publishedDate")]
    public string publishdate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("estimatedLaunchDate")]
    public string estimatedLaunchDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("createdTime")]
    public string createtime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastUpdatedTime")]
    public string lastupdate { get; set; }

    public Product product { get; set; }
}

public class Product 
{
    public DateTime estimatedLocationDate { get; set; }

    /* Other members, if necessary */
}

string result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Planet>(jsonString).product.estimatedLocationDate;
```

Note that:

- JSON you have posted is invalid. Let's suppose that you have copied not the whole JSON, and ignore this since "The other decorated values return the proper values."
- It is better to give `UpperCamelCase` names to C# properties

Comment: *The other decorated values return the proper values* that's clearly not a code.

Comment: @yeldar-kurmangaliyev : The json field "planet" is an array, please update your code to parse from planet array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inner class for the Product, and expose it using a property like so.

```
public class JsonNet
{
    public static string jsonString = @"{ ""inner"" : { ""name"" : ""myname""}}";

    public static Test GetTest()
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(jsonString);
    }
}

public class Inner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public Inner Inner { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return Inner.Name; }
        set { Inner.Name = value; }
    }
}
```